# Make Planar Grid And Axis Visible

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

I am looking to display a 3D planar grid and X,Y,Z axis in a SCNView, similarly to XCode 3D/asset editor/viewer.

Are there some built-in properties/methods to do so (have looked at the refc pages but could not see any)? Or would one need to just code the rendering? Any good pointer to get started on this? (surely this has been done many times before)